Getting ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleStart called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
I have downloaded latest jmeter 5.6.3 and downloaded jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config and set the path to driver, used Chrome driver version /128.0.6613.137/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
I just ran simple code which will launch a URL and close.
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

When i ran it getting below error in jmeter log,But its capturing response times ,is it reliable? can you let us know what is wrong here.(Java Version used 11.0.18)

ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleStart called twice
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence





I cannot reproduce your issue using JMeter 5.6.3 and WebDriver Sampler 4.13.0.0.
You can try

installing clean vanilla JMeter 5.6.3
the latest version of the WebDriver Sampler using JMeter Plugins Manager

If the issue persists you can increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level and see if you can get the root cause from jmeter.log file

I have followed above steps and still facing the issue here is the Log:-

ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1198) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3] at om.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:104) [jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)

Issue resolved after downgrading the WebDriver version to 4.13.0.0,seems a bug in version 4.13.0.1
